# wxPython, multiline label on wxButton

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm trying to get a label on a button to be on two or more lines. I want to update this at runtime. I did like this:

```
self.btnGroupOne.SetLabel(u"test\ntest")
```

Yet, when I run the app, i just get a button with "testtest" on a single line as the label.

Am I forgetting a property that allows multiline labels or something?

BTW, when I do this:

```
self.btnNieuwTicket = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Nieuw\nTicket", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size( 80,80 ), 0 )
```

the multiline does work...

- Platform: Windows, both 7 64bit and XP tested
- wxPython version: 2.8 unicode
- Python version: 2.7.1

Comment: I am able to duplicate this behavior.  There's no style I'm aware of that would control or affect the behavior either.  Weird ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to be a confirmed bug in wxWidgets:
http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/12491

If you give the button a multi-line label at creation, `SetLabel` will then allow multiple lines.

Comment: where do you give a button "multi-line" ?

Comment: @BerryTsakala You create the button with label text containing a newline character: `wx.Button(self, -1, label='\n')`

Comment: Thanks. I just realized it's possible with wxFormBuilder, by pressing the [...] button next to the button's "label" property.